# Python Thread does not run

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm making server program on Python with threads, where you can register, login, etc. with `socket` module. I also used `threading` module to handle multiple users, but when I ran my program, it threw an error.

Here is my code:

```
import threading
import socket
import json

host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 8765

print("IP:", host)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))

with open("users.json") as file:
    users = json.load(file)["users"]

cnts = []

def client():
    c, a = s.accept()

    acc = None

    while 1:
        req = c.recv(1)

        if req == b"b":
            break

        elif req == b"r":
            name = c.recv(c.recv(1)[0])

            if len(name) < 3:
                c.send("\x01")
            elif len(name) > 20:
                c.send("\x02")
            elif name in users:
                c.send("\x03")
            else:
                pwd = c.recv(c.recv(1)[0])

                if len(pwd) < 4:
                    c.send("\x01")
                elif len(pwd) > 12:
                    c.send("\x02")
                else:
                    c.send("\x00")

                    users[name] = pwd
                    acc = name

        elif req == b"s":
            name = c.recv(c.recv(1)[0])

            if name in users:
                pwd = c.recv(c.recv(1)[0])

                if users[name] == pwd:
                    acc = name
                    c.send("\x00")
                else:
                    c.send("\x02")
            else:
                c.send("\x01")

    c.close()

s.listen(1)
quit = 0

while not quit:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=client)
    thread.start()

    cnts.append(thread)
```

Porgram Output:

```
> py server.py
IP: 192.168.0.106
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 72, in <module>
    thread.start()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 852, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

I'm new to python threading, so I don't understand what I did wrong.

EDIT: Already fixed. Thanks for answers.

New code:

```
import threading
import socket
import json

host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 8765

print("IP:", host)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))

with open("users.json") as file:
    users = json.load(file)["users"]

cnts = []
waiting = 1

def client():
    global waiting
    c, a = s.accept()
    waiting = 0

    acc = None

    while 1:
        req = c.recv(1)

        if req == b"b":
            break

        elif req == b"r":
            name = c.recv(c.recv(1)[0])

            if len(name) < 3:
                c.send("\x01")
            elif len(name) > 20:
                c.send("\x02")
            elif name in users:
                c.send("\x03")
            else:
                pwd = c.recv(c.recv(1)[0])

                if len(pwd) < 4:
                    c.send("\x01")
                elif len(pwd) > 12:
                    c.send("\x02")
                else:
                    c.send("\x00")

                    users[name] = pwd
                    acc = name

        elif req == b"s":
            name = c.recv(c.recv(1)[0])

            if name in users:
                pwd = c.recv(c.recv(1)[0])

                if users[name] == pwd:
                    acc = name
                    c.send("\x00")
                else:
                    c.send("\x02")
            else:
                c.send("\x01")

    c.close()

s.listen(1)
quit = 0

counter = 0

while not quit:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=client)
    thread.start()

    cnts.append(thread)
    counter += 1

    while waiting:
        pass

    waiting = 1
```

Comment: It appears to me as if you wrote a thread bomb. In your while loop you start threads indefinitely until an operating system limit is reached and you get the runtime error.

Comment: Your program starts an infinite number of threads until something causes it to not be able to create any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while not quit:` body has no anything blocking the execution, like `input`,  `socket.recv`, or `time.sleep`. That means, this loop does every iteration quite fast and on every iteration creates a new thread. Try to replace `while not quit:` by, for instance, `for _ in range(3)` to spawn only 3 threads.